# Is there a C++ lib for eMule protocol just like libtorrent for BT protocol

Tags: c++

I want to deploy a project that could simply down some file through the emule protocol.
but I couldn't find any lib for emule (Only emule ,but it's hard for me)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any nice library for protocols used by eMule. You can look at aMule project, it should be little more readable, it is cross platform and there is a version without GUI.
http://www.amule.org/